# what is the proper configuration for rabbitmq aws autodiscovery plugin

Tags: rabbitmq

I am trying to set up a RabbitMQ cluster behind an ELB in an autoscaling group on AWS. While building the clustering manually works, thus confirming that the instances have the proper security groups and roles to detect each other, I am unclear on the configuration of the [auto-discovery plugin](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-peer-discovery-aws) that the clustering guide [recommends](https://www.rabbitmq.com/cluster-formation.html#peer-discovery-aws). I am using RabbitMQ 3.7.2 and the plugin is installed correctly.

```
$ rabbitmqctl status
Status of node rabbit@ip-172-xxx ...
[{pid,4904},
 {running_applications,
     [{rabbitmq_peer_discovery_aws,
          "AWS-based RabbitMQ peer discovery backend","3.7.2"},
      {rabbitmq_peer_discovery_common,
          "Modules shared by various peer discovery backends","3.7.2"},
      {rabbit,"RabbitMQ","3.7.2"},
      {rabbit_common,
          "Modules shared by rabbitmq-server and rabbitmq-erlang-client",
          "3.7.2"},
      {rabbitmq_aws,
          "A minimalistic AWS API interface used by rabbitmq-autocluster (3.6.x) and other RabbitMQ plugins",
          "3.7.2"},
      {os_mon,"CPO  CXC 138 46","2.4.3"},
      {mnesia,"MNESIA  CXC 138 12","4.15.1"},
      {lager,"Erlang logging framework","3.5.1"},
      {ranch_proxy_protocol,"Ranch Proxy Protocol Transport","1.4.4"},
      {ranch,"Socket acceptor pool for TCP protocols.","1.4.0"},
      {ssl,"Erlang/OTP SSL application","8.2.1"},
      {public_key,"Public key infrastructure","1.5"},
      {asn1,"The Erlang ASN1 compiler version 5.0.3","5.0.3"},
      {crypto,"CRYPTO","4.1"},
      {xmerl,"XML parser","1.3.15"},
      {inets,"INETS  CXC 138 49","6.4.2"},
      {jsx,"a streaming, evented json parsing toolkit","2.8.2"},
      {recon,"Diagnostic tools for production use","2.3.2"},
      {goldrush,"Erlang event stream processor","0.1.9"},
      {compiler,"ERTS  CXC 138 10","7.1.2"},
      {syntax_tools,"Syntax tools","2.1.3"},
      {sasl,"SASL  CXC 138 11","3.1"},
      {stdlib,"ERTS  CXC 138 10","3.4.2"},
      {kernel,"ERTS  CXC 138 10","5.4"}]},
 {os,{unix,linux}},
 {erlang_version,
     "Erlang/OTP 20 [erts-9.1] [source] [64-bit] [smp:1:1] [ds:1:1:10] [async-threads:64] [hipe] [kernel-poll:true]\n"},
 {memory,
     [{connection_readers,14208},
      {connection_writers,0},
      {connection_channels,0},
      {connection_other,17536},
      {queue_procs,0},
      {queue_slave_procs,0},
      {plugins,25608},
      {other_proc,26377728},
      {metrics,184432},
      {mgmt_db,0},
      {mnesia,79832},
      {other_ets,1938864},
      {binary,1129008},
      {msg_index,29360},
      {code,25069173},
      {atom,1041593},
      {other_system,9184858},
      {allocated_unused,15000984},
      {reserved_unallocated,0},
      {strategy,rss},
      {total,[{erlang,65092200},{rss,76500992},{allocated,80093184}]}]},
 {alarms,[]},
 {listeners,[{clustering,25672,"::"},{amqp,5672,"::"}]},
 {vm_memory_calculation_strategy,rss},
 {vm_memory_high_watermark,0.4},
 {vm_memory_limit,415571968},
 {disk_free_limit,50000000},
 {disk_free,6836322304},
 {file_descriptors,
     [{total_limit,924},{total_used,4},{sockets_limit,829},{sockets_used,2}]},
 {processes,[{limit,1048576},{used,216}]},
 {run_queue,0},
 {uptime,2707},
 {kernel,{net_ticktime,60}}]
```

My question is related to these fields from the documentation:

```
cluster_formation.peer_discovery_backend = rabbit_peer_discovery_aws
cluster_formation.aws.region = us-east-1
cluster_formation.aws.access_key_id = ANIDEXAMPLE
cluster_formation.aws.secret_key = WjalrxuTnFEMI/K7MDENG+bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY
cluster_formation.aws.use_autoscaling_group = true
```

Where are these fields supposed to be added and in which format? Should it be in /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.config or somewhere else? Can someone provide a configuration example?

Comment: I really want this plugin to work - and looks like I'm having similar problems. Were you able to solve this problem? can you offer an working configuration?

Comment: Not really, I actually had to downsize to a lower RabbitMQ version and use a boot startup script

Comment: yup. same here. shame - this has a lot of potential.

Answer (score 0):

Configuration will be as follows:

```
{rabbit, [
    {cluster_formation, [
        {peer_discovery_backend, rabbit_peer_discovery_aws},
        {peer_discovery_aws, [
            {aws_ec2_region, "us-east-1"},
            {aws_autoscaling, true}
        ]}, 
        {node_cleanup, [
            {cleanup_only_log_warning, false}
        ]}
    ]}
}
```

[priv/schema/rabbit.schema](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/blob/master/priv/schema/rabbit.schema) in rabbitmq-server and [priv/schema/rabbitmq_peer_discovery_aws.schema](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-peer-discovery-aws/blob/master/priv/schema/rabbitmq_peer_discovery_aws.schema) in rabbitmq-peer-discovery-aws plugin sources have some mappings between new and old configuration format

I would suggest to use [IAM Instance Profiles](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_switch-role-ec2_instance-profiles.html) to provide credentials to EC2 instances. With example provided it will automatically pick those up.